# How to access dynamic path for "Libs" folder in android studio , using Java code?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, path, android-source

I have modified android studio to add some extra features in it. Now, I want to run my **xyz.batch** file from the **Run...** button of android studio. **I can run batch file by placing it in "libs" folder and simply run it.**

[image]

But I want to run android project as well as my own .bat or .exe file from Run button(both at same time on same click)

[image]

It's possible if i provide path of .batch file for that  I have also modified the code related to "Run...." button . (added some Extra code:)

```
  Process p =Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c C:\Users\User_Name\AndroidStudioProjects\App_Name\app\libs\xyz.bat");
```

**I want to access  .batch file in "libs" folder. the path for this is:**

> **C:\Users\User_Name\AndroidStudioProjects\App_Name\app\libs\xyz.bat**

But here **User_Name** and **App_Name** is dynamic.
How to achive this dynamic path in my Java code?